Reversed hashing algo using subtle crypto
Update: Just adding a highly desired feature - it'd great to have "sibling" hashes to recognize each other as such. So for any set of the non-deterministic hashes it will be possible to tell if they were produced for the same source value without revealing the latter.
I'm looking for an algorithm producing different hash (or whatever you call them) values for every hashing attempt while keeping the hashes verifiable (i.e. for any "source-hash" pair it should be possible to tell if they're related). I'm using subtle crypto, tried both hashes and signatures the both seem to produce the same hash/signature for the same source value.
I'm learning crypto, here's a bit more formal definition of what I'm trying to achieve:

A - source value
fHash(A) - a function, returning unique hash values for every call
fVerify(A, hash) - a function returning true or false,indicating whether the hash produced for A.
fAreSiblings(hash1, hash2) - a function returning true if hashes are produced for the same source value (note, the actual source value is unknown).


Is there anything wrong with simply adding a counter or any other unique identifier to a hash? You can also publish a 128 bit (or so) random and include that in the hash calculation in case it is impossible to agree on a unique value. SubtleCrypto is an API that implements standardized algorithms; the fundamental output of the hashes is not determined by the API but by the algorithms. For instance, RSA-PKCS1 signature generation is deterministic, while RSA-PSS is not.

Sure. I know that hash consistency is key, which is why I said I'm not even sure if it's the hash. With a centralized system you can add salt or whatever, with a decentralized one I'd rather deal with something working out of the box for everyone. The idea is to add some level of privacy to the assets stored in a blockchain, as you might guess.

Replacing a pubkey with a fixed derived value is a privacy deal breaker. Having variant hashes isn't a radical solution for it neither, but it will makes things a bit less transparent. A good solution would be to encrypt public keys for the parties interested in them using their pubkeys. Just looking at the options available.

@Maarten - If I understand you correctly - Let's say you prepend that hash with a guid. While it will make hashes unique it'd also be extremally easy to use dictionaries of <PubLicKey, Hash> to ruin the privacy, people will just dump the "dummy" part of the hash. With true variant hashes you'd need to have <PublicKey, List> dictionary with up to date List values to get things working, which is more difficult.

Do you have a specific use case in mind, or is this just something that sounds neat?  As it is written, it can be addressed by fairly trivial methods (such as what PeterRindal suggested) - it would appear likely that such a method really wouldn't satisfy something that really needs this functionality; however without a use case in front of us, it's impossible to say.

I have a use case - I need to protect users transactions from being "looked-up", or at least make it harder to do so. Accounts are used as public keys short references, they stay in the blockchain. Having non-deterministic hashes will make it harder to trace it back to the "identity" as you'd need to maintain "also-known-as" lookups. Btw - on a second thought - having sibling recognition might actually defeat the purpose, so I'd scratch it for now.

Let $H$ be a random oracle, i.e. a perfect hash function that for each input (source) $x$, outputs a uniformly random $y=H(x)$.
$fHash(x)$:

sample a random string $r\gets\{0,1\}^\kappa$
let $h_1 = H(x)$
let $h_2 = H(r,x)$
return $(r,h_1,h_2)$

$fVerify(x,h):$

Parse $(r,h_1,h_2)=h$.
return $fHash(x;r)=h$.

$fAreSiblings(h,h'):$

let $(r,h_1,h_2)=h$ and $(r',h_1',h_2')=h'$.
return $h_1=h_1'$.

One potential problem with the above is that its easy to make $fAreSiblings$ output true when the hashes are actually malformed. For example, $fAreSiblings$ would return true for $(0,32423,0), (1,32423,1)$ but its unlikely these are actually valid hashes. If you want to verify the whole hash in $fAreSiblings$, then you could use a zero knowledge proof of knowledge (ZKPOK) to prove that someone known an input and randomness that was used to correctly build the hash.
$fHash(x)$:

sample a random string $r\gets\{0,1\}^\kappa$
let $h_1 = H(x)$
let $h_2 = H(r,x)$
let $z = ZKPOK\{ (x,r) | h_1=H(x),h_2=H(r,x) \}$
return $(r,h_1,h_2)$

$fVerify(x,h):$

Parse $(r,h_1,h_2)=h$.
return $fHash(x;r)=h$.

$fAreSiblings(h,h'):$

let $(r,h_1,h_2,z)=h$ and $(r',h_1',h_2',z')=h'$.
return $h_1=h_1'$ and $ZKVerify(z)=1$ and $ZKVerify(z')=1$.


thanks for a thorough one but you had me at hello here I'm afraid... I was looking for a way to achieve this using subtle crypto domain functional...

ok, use the first solution. Surely it has a normal hash function $H$. For example, use $H=SHA3$.
